# Xcode can't find my .h file that was made in the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

Disregard the typo in the body of the @implementation where the view controller being called is different than the one being imported. I've fixed that and the error still occurs..

I can't figure out why it doesn't find the file when the file is clearly within the project..

And it does this for every file that is in the Models, Views and Controller files..

Comment: Clear project, delete DerivedData and restart Xcode.

Comment: @dasdom so you're saying  I should deleted everything and start over? thanks

Comment: No, I don't. Select Product in the Menu and select Clear. Go to the Organizer. Select your project and press the button Delete in the line of the DerivedData. Then restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "Controllers" folder is a folder reference and not a group. That is why it is blue and not yellow like the other groups in your project. Remove the folder reference and add the "Controllers" folder as a group to your project. To do this, when you drag the folder into your project, in the dialog that appears make sure to choose "Create groups for any added folders" and **not** "Create folder references for any added folders". The "Models" and "Views" folders will also need to be fixed.

When you have a folder reference the files will be added to the product of the target, but not compiled.

Comment: ^ He is correct. These folders should be groups (they should be brown not blue).

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't attached imgur pictures... You can attach them inline with your post.
2. Ensure that your header is included with the linked headers under the build information.
3. Run a clean build and ensure you're running the regular target and not the test target.
4. If your file is included during compilation (aka your build settings include it) then restart Xcode.

Comment: You can't attach pictures w/o enough rep.

Comment: You're correct in that, you should still use something like flickr. Using imgur for that just makes you look bad. I do admit, I stand corrected though as I forgot that was a starting limitation.

Comment: imgur is the official image hosting site for StackExchange: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Comment: Hosts and links directly out to are two different things, I was just providing a word of advice for the internet. Take it or leave it lol.

Answer (score 0):

I press <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to add the folder and got this issue.

A simple image to solve the issue:

[image]

Make sure you selected the "**Create groups**", I must clicked the "*Create folder references*" by mistake sometime before